# How to use a 4 part naming convention to call a linked server within an "updates statistics" job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am setting up a job on an Integration server to run a statistic update on my client database.

The problem is that the update statistics syntax will not allow me to call a 4-part name.

I would like to do something like this:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [linked server].[database].[dbo].[table] 

WITH FULLSCAN

GO
```

But I'm getting an error stating that the max number of prefixes has been exceeded.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I really don't have the option to put this locally on my client database.

ANSWER FOUND

Thanks to everybody who threw their hats at this one but I actually found a really cool workaround for this one and hopefully it can help someone else.

```
EXEC [linked_server].[database].[sys].[sp_executesql] N'UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo].[table] WITH FULLSCAN'
```

This can be used for truncation, trigger enable and disable, and other functions of SQL that are not allowed across linked servers.

From what I understand it passes the statement through the linked server rather then the execution.

Comment: You cannot, `UPDATE STATISTICS` has a limitation of accepting only two.part object name. it means you will have to be on that server and in the database context to execute this command.

Comment: What about creating a stored procedure on the client database that runs `UPDATE STATISTICS`. Then on your integration server create a job that execute that stored procedure.

Comment: I just came across this as well is there a way to set up the client as a target server and pass the job without it living on the client server

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I would try creating a [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx). Like: `CREATE SYNONYM my_remote_table FOR [linked server].[database].[dbo].[table]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably wouldn't want to get around this limitation as it would seem unwise to do across a distributed transaction ;-). But you are in luck. You are already using SSIS. Just have SSIS connect to the proper server and do the `UPDATE STATISTICS` via that direct / local connection.

Additionally, since you are using SSIS, it has a task for Updating Statistics:

- [Update Statistics Task (Maintenance Plan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178678.aspx)
- [Update Statistics Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137599.aspx)